# Is the phrase "My current educational and residential situation" correct?

Tags: phrases, idioms

Is the phrase

> ... because of my current educational and residential situation

a correct way to refer to where and why I study what I do and why I live where I do? Or should it be "education and residence situation"?

Comment: why do you think you need to include _situation_? and I think "my current education and residence" is far better. (Although after reading "By that I mean where and why I study this and why I live there.", I don't think either of those phrases fits.)

Comment: @DanD. I'm using 'situation', because I want to say why I am doing these courses, why I had to do them and why I'm living there... Basically the situation I'm in, at the moment, in terms of education and residence. How do you think I should say it?

Comment: Saras, I edited question to reflect what I think you are asking; please edit it yourself if necessary.  One should adjust the question by editing it, rather than via comments.

Comment: Per Daniel's answer, it looks at the very least "stilted". Personally, I would go for *current educational and residential circumstances* if you want a minimal change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Educational* and *residential* are the adjectival forms of *education* and *residence*, so they would be correct.  However, this construction looks a little stilted, so I would suggest *my current situation in terms of residence and education.*

Comment: "In terms of" sounds awkward to me.  How about simply "regarding?"

Comment: To me, "education" implies completeness while "educational situation" implies the speaker is currently taking courses.